# Automatic closing JS Alert window in GWT

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

How can I automatically close the Window.alert() in GWT after a certain time?
The problem is, that I want to notify the user of new things, but the Window.alert() will block the application until the "OK" Button has been clicked.

Answer (score 2):

You can not close the dialog created by Window.alert(), but you can use a normal GWT Dialog and display that to your user. It can be closed programmatically.

Take a look at: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DialogBox.html

Comment: thanks a lot, but the problen of the dialofBox is, thaat if the user is on another tab or another window he will not know that there is a dialog box...